# Вытащить в текстовое поле

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Как из

```
<div class='panel' style='width:200px;'  id='d_{$row['id']}'>
{$row['id']}  {$row['name']}<div class='selo' >
```

Вытащить в `<input id="tex" type="text" name="tex">` поле `{$row['name']}` в модальное окно?

```
<?php
require_once "conf.php";
?>

<head>

<body> 
<?php

dbConnect();

$zapros=mysql_query("select * from spr_otdel") or die (mysql_error);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($zapros)){
echo "
<div class='panel' style='width:200px;'  id='d_{$row['id']}'>
{$row['id']}  {$row['name']}<div class='selo' ><a href='#' class='btn-delete'  onclick='return delet(\"{$row['id']}\")'>Удалить</a> | <a href='#' class='edit'>Редактировать</a></div></div>";
}
?>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
.panel {
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px;
    position: relative;
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc
    }
.alt {
    background: #f5f4f4;
    }
.selo {
    font-size: 8pt;
    }
</style>

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".panel:even").addClass("alt");
        $(".panel .edit").click(function(){
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });

$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ buttons: [
    {
        text: "Ok",
        click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }

    }
]

 })})});

function delet(id) {

        $( "#del" ).dialog({ 
        title:"удаляем сообщение",
        buttons:
    {
        "Да": function() {
        $("#d_"+id).animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
        .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
        $(this).dialog("close");},
        "Нет": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }

    }
 });     
        return false;

    }

</script> 
<div id="del" style='display:none;text-align:center;font-size:10px;'>
точно хотите удалить?
</div>
<div id="dialog" style='display:none;font-size:10px;' title='редактируем'>
<input id="tex" type="textarea">

</div>
</head>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: new_russian_man, я думаю на форуме много людей, который могут вам помочь, но можно не создавать одинаковые вопросы с не ясной формулировкой. Начните с описания вашей цели и на каком вы этапе и что именно не получается.

Comment: Поддерживаю.. совсем не интересно читать километр кода с неясно с формулированной задачей.

Answer (score 1):

Подключаем библиотеку jquery

Код js:

```
var data;
data=$('div.panel').html();
document.GetElementById('tex').value=data;
```

Вторая строчка передаёт переменной data всё, что заключено в тег 'div' класса 'panel' (Спасибо библиотеке jquery). 
Третья строчка записывает переменную 'data' в инпут с "id='text'"

но лучше так:

```
document.GetElementById('tex').value=$('div.panel').html();
```